# Angular 7 Display table headers programmatically - *ngFor and *ngIf on same selector

Tags: angular, html-table, ngfor

I have an object that defines the headers that a table must have, some of these headers are set to hidden and must not show on the table.

```
sampleTable: {
headers: [{
  name: 'Description',
  isHidden: false
}, {
  name: 'Active',
  isHidden: false
}, {
  name: 'Code',
  isHidden: false
}, {
  name: 'recordId',
  isHidden: true,
}]
}
```

In this example, the header named "recordId" is set to `hidden = true` which means it must `NOT DISPLAY`

I have tried the obvious:

```
<tr>
  <th>Fixed Column start</th>
  <th *ngFor="let header of sampleTable.headers" *ngIf="!header.isHidden">{{header.name}}</th>
  <th>Fixed Column end</th>
</tr>
```

Angular does not support 2 structural directives on the same element.

Subsequently, I have tried:

```
<tr>
  <th>Fixed Column start</th>
   <template *ngFor="let header of resourceConfiguration.headers">
      <th *ngIf="header.isHidden === true" [nzWidth]="header.width" nzAlign="left">{{header.name}}</th>
    </template>
  <th>Fixed Column end</th>
</tr>
```

But it only displays the 2 fixed columns.

How can I hide programmatically hide some column?

I know there are several other similar questions but i could not find a solution to this problem although it looks straight forward. Having fixed columns at the beginning and the end complicates this.

The table is a reusable component and based on a configuration object must display different columns.

Comment: Have you tried `ng-container` instead of `template`?Not even sure if `template` exists in angular but `ng-template` does.

Comment: <ng-container> is working exactly as i want. Thank you, i wonder why didn't i think about it first. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use ng-container instead of ng-template.

EG:

```html
    <tr>
      <th>Fixed Column start</th>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let header of resourceConfiguration.headers">
          <th *ngIf="header.isHidden === true" [nzWidth]="header.width" nzAlign="left">{{header.name}}</th>
        </ng-container>
      <th>Fixed Column end</th>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all what you are trying to achieve is already solved and you will have a lot of features available. I would highlight the capability of creating custom behaviours to this component.

My recomendation is Angular DataTables https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

If you need help with the implementation do not hesitate, drop me a line.
Happy Coding